# cURL in java for instagram API

Tags: java, api, curl, instagram

How i can POST this cURL using java?

```
 curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you POST in Java (from [here](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-java.html))

```
    public static String httpPost(String urlStr, String[] paramName,
String[] paramVal) throws Exception {
  URL url = new URL(urlStr);
  HttpURLConnection conn =
      (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setUseCaches(false);
  conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  // Create the form content
  OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
  Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
  for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) {
    writer.write(paramName[i]);
    writer.write("=");
    writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(paramVal[i], "UTF-8"));
    writer.write("&");
  }
  writer.close();
  out.close();

  if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
  }

  // Buffer the result into a string
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
  }
  rd.close();

  conn.disconnect();
  return sb.toString();
}
```

A better way to use the Instagram API in Java would be to use a Java library that someone else wrote called [JInstagram](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram).